# Error while using @ElementCollection: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: for columns

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistent

I have two tables `NewsToolSearchCriteria` and `NewsToolSearchCriteria_NewsSource_Relation`. 
`newsToolSearchCriteriaId` is the foreign key references to `NewsToolSearchCriteria (entityID)` I want to see a set of elements from the second table inside first.

Trying to set it up this way:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "NewsToolSearchCriteria_NewsSource_Relation", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "newsToolSearchCriteriaId"))
@Column(name = "newsSourceCode")
private Set<String> newsSources;

public Set<String> getNewsSources() {
    return newsSources;
}

public void setNewsSources(Set<String> newsSources) {
    this.newsSources = newsSources;
}
```

But keep receiving the error:

> nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: dbo.NewsToolSearchCriteria, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(newsSources)]

I've already tried to use `@Column(name = "newsSourceCode", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(30)")` and `@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)`

I already saw other similar questions but it is not the case where I using two entities and it could be resolved using`@OneToMany`.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How does your table `NewsToolSearchCriteria_NewsSource_Relation` look like? You might want to try `@JoinTable` instead of `@CollectionTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add annotations on getter instead of a class parameter.

I did not find the place where it said, but they use it in [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html) and it works for me.